# Can't installl devdocs for offline browsing

Tags: macos, installation, offline-browsing

I have problem installing [devdocs](https://github.com/Thibaut/devdocs) in my mac.
I tried to do the steps there but I'm stucked installing bundler.

I tried the following in the terminal:

`gem install bundler        //this worked

bundle install             //this prints error: Bundler::GemfileNotFound`

I already have the latest Ruby version required but still printing the same error.

I tried to execute `bundle install` in the path where the gemfile is still the same error.

I needed to install this in my pc for offline browsing. For those who successfully installed this in their mac machine, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that you're trying to run the command in a directory that does not contain any Gemfile. I think that in your local directory, you forgot to clone the devdocs Git repo. So go to your local devdocs directory and type:

`git clone https://github.com/Thibaut/devdocs`

Then go to this directory, and type the following commands:

```
bundle install
thor docs:download --all
rackup
```

That should work, and devdocs should be available at localhost:9292. If that does not, maybe your ruby version is too old (devdocs requires Ruby 2.1.0 or greater). In this case, I strongly recommend you to us rvm to update ruby (rvm install ruby-2.1.0).

Comment: Wow! This solve my problem! :) Thanks so much! I successfully installed devdocs now. :)